# PHP Header in CRON Job not working

Tags: php, cron

I am using this code `header('Location: http://example.com/test.php?number='.$requestsDone.'');`

But looks like it is not working, what is wrong here?

Let me know, if you need more information.

Comment: Why are you setting headers in a cron job?

Comment: As you can see, i am sending a `GET` value, i need that GET value in my code. 

The code works fine in google chrome, but not when using CRON job

Comment: Maybe you want `file_get_contents('http://example.com/test.php?number='.$requestsDone.'');` not sure...

Comment: `header('Location: ...')` redirects a browser. There's no browser in a cron job.

Comment: Not that Abra.  And ceejayoz, i did not know that. What is the solution bro?

Comment: @Toby No clue. You haven't told us what the point of this is. What are you trying to accomplish? Why doesn't Abra's good suggestion of `file_get_contents` accomplish what you want?

Comment: Based on Toby's first comment, it works in chrome because the script is doing some work, then redirecting to test.php to do some more work.  Best guess is the cron job needs to do the same thing, but the script needs to redirect or make a request depending on how its executed.

Comment: @ceejayoz It gives me server timed out. Because the page keep on reloading (infinite)

Answer (score 1):

Producing a header in a command line script doesn't make any sense. The header is part of the HTTP protocol, there is no HTTP involved when the script is executed using the [CLI version of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php).

Accordingly, the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function is not implemented in the CLI version of PHP. It exists, but [it doesn't produce any output](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php).

Also, the [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) that contain information extracted from the HTTP request (`$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]`, `$_REQUEST[]`, `$_FILES[]`, `$_COOKIE[]` etc) exist but they are empty.

In order to pass arguments to a script using the command line, use the [`$argc`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [`$argv[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variables.

Comment: What is the solution?