# PHP - header() to self, does this start a new process?

Tags: php, cron, header

**The Setup**

I have a PHP script that relocates to itself. Something like...

```
if($val) {
    header('Location: ' . ROOTPATH . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    die();
}
```

**The Problem**

The script crawls through a table row-by-row, where it takes *at least* 45s to process each row. The table could be empty, or it could have hundreds of rows. The script exits once it has reached the end of the table.

If I simply use a loop to go through the table, I'd almost certainly end up triggering the `default_socket_timeout`, with the handling of each row taking so long. Instead, I've opted to create a new process of itself, while terminating the current one.

**The Question**

But does this work the way I'm thinking? With the `header()` followed by `die()`, am I creating a new process on a separate thread, and terminating the current (old) one? Or do they stack-up recursively inside one another, only compounding the issue I'm trying to avoid?

***Also... (awe, crap)***

I'm currently using a browser for testing everything, but this script will eventually be initiated by a CRON-Job. While typing this up, I had an feeling that `header()` wouldn't work for a process running via CRON, and [I was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953976/php-header-in-cron-job-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top). Bah. Humbug.

I am still interested in knowing about the original question with the `header()` - since I'll be using it for testing - but now I have a new problem, in that I need to somehow reinitialize a script from within that same script (on a separate thread/process, while simultaneously terminating the current script). All in a manner that is CRON-friendly.

I tried looking for solutions to this new problem, but nothing is coming up. Perhaps there is a jargon word for this problem, that I'm not familiar with?

**Thanks!**

Comment: I'd be concerned about your 45 Seconds per row issue... Do you fully understand why it takes that long before trying to work around it?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes. The script depends on pulling data from a few external sources (there is no way around this), as well as parsing and validating much of the returned data. PHP functions like `file_get_html()` and `simplexml_load_string()` are painfully slow - and entirely dependent on the server(s) serving-up the data. I wish there were a better way.

Comment: Something I did once for tackling that sort of cron problem, was I made the first execution of the php generate a dynamic on-the-fly crontab file, into a 'crons/minute-crons/' directory (which crontab is set to simply run them every minute if they exist). The "Minute-Cron" then runs and deletes itself so it never runs again, but makes a new one at the end if it still needs to continue a lengthy process. Kind of a crazy self replicating thing, and you have to be very careful how you set it up haha, it can get away from you!

Comment: If you run it per cron / php-cli, then the socket timeout loses its relevancy. (Still would make sense to split it up / use a task queue of sorts however.)

Comment: @mario Because there are (potentially) so many rows, I'm trying to avoid waiting for the next CRON to fire. I think every minute is the minimum resolution? I track the processes as they are initialized and terminated - so I can limit the number of simultaneous processes. But, in the interest of not having to wait for a new CRON to fire, I can trigger a new process from within as soon as the current one is done. And when the next CRON triggers, it'll create a new process if the current number isn't too high.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think header does what you think it does, it just sets an HTTP response header. In 'Location:'s case, its a 302 redirect to another URL. The browser will follow the link and the browser might kick off a new process if it hits another page. But this won't work in a cron, as the http response headers aren't received at all.

Comment: Also to note, that header redirect only happens once the initial php script is done executing, so it will not spawn off 100 requests all at once. It would do one, then spit the header out to the browser to hit the php again to do the next. And yes, not useful in crons.

Comment: @Randall One at a time is fine, and actually preferred so I can track them more easily. Eventually, between the CRON and the running processes both triggering new processes, the number of simultaneous processes (which I monitor, and limit to a ceiling) will quickly saturate to.